# Angular error : Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependencies, mean-stack

I keep getting this error when trying to run my app :

```
bundle.js:188 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate      
module app due to:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setKey' of undefined
```

Here is my app.js file

```
require('angular')
require('angular-route')

var app = angular.module('app',['ngRoute'])

require('./services/car_service')(app);
require('./services/auth_service')(app);
require('./services/error_service')(app);
require('./controllers/car-controller.js')(app)
require('./controllers/user-controller.js')(app)

app.config(['$routeProvider', function(router, filepickerProvider) {
  router
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
    })
    .when('/login', {
      controller: 'UserController',
      controllerAs: 'userctrl',
      templateUrl: 'templates/login.html'
    })
    .when('/submit', {
      templateUrl: 'templates/submit.html'
    })
    .when('/inventory', {
      templateUrl: 'templates/inventory.html'
    })
    .when('/new-admin', {
      templateUrl: 'templates/new-admin.html'
    })
    .when('/admin-view', {
      templateUrl: 'templates/admin-view.html'
    })
    filepickerProvider.setKey(FILEPICKER);
 }])
```

I am not sure what I am missing but any advice or suggestions would be great.

Comment: You don't inject `filepickerProvider` properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seens that you are missing the injection of the file picker in your app module.

That is causing your filepickerProvider to be null.

try to do the follow:

```
`var app = angular.module('app',['ngRoute', 'angular-filepicker'])
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: So when I try that it gives me another error:

    bundle.js:177 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate    module app due to:
    Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module  filepickerProvider due to:
    Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'filepickerProvider' is not available!    You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a    module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second    argument.

I am not sure what is causing this. It is part of the angular-filepicker package installed through bower.

Comment: are you using https://github.com/filepicker/filepicker-angular right? Are you sure that you have both <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/filepicker-js/dist/filepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-filepicker/dist/angular_filepicker.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

For noob people like me, make sure all the paths to the files are correct, especially to your js files.